# C# Bouncy Castle: AES CTR why it's not auto-incremented

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes, bouncycastle

I'm trying to implement AES 128 CTR encryption in c#. I've found Bouncy Castle is very useful. Here is my code:

```
public class AESCrypto
{
   private byte[] Key = new byte[16];
   private byte[] IV = new byte[16];
   private const int CHUNK_SIZE = 16;
   private IBufferedCipher cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("AES/CTR/NoPadding");

   // Key and IV I get from client.
   public AESCrypto(byte[] key, byte[] iv, bool forEncryption) {
      Key = key;
      IV = iv;
      cipher.Init(forEncryption, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(Key), IV));
   }

   public byte[] PerformAES(byte[] incomingBytes)
   {
            int blockCount = incomingBytes.Length / CHUNK_SIZE; // Number of blocks
            int blockRemaining = incomingBytes.Length % CHUNK_SIZE; // Remaining bytes of the last block

            byte[] outcomingBytes = new byte[incomingBytes.Length];

            for (var i = 0; i < blockCount; i++)
            {
                // Why do I need to re-init it again?
                //cipher.Init(false, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(Key), IV));

                byte[] temp = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
                Array.Copy(incomingBytes, i * CHUNK_SIZE, temp, 0, CHUNK_SIZE);

                byte[] decryptedChunk = cipher.ProcessBytes(temp);
                Array.Copy(decryptedChunk, 0, outcomingBytes, i * CHUNK_SIZE, CHUNK_SIZE);
                //Increase(IV); Why do I need to increse iv by hand?
            }

            if (blockRemaining != 0)
            {
                // Why do I need to re-init it again?
                //cipher.Init(false, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(Key), IV));

                byte[] temp = new byte[blockRemaining];
                Array.Copy(incomingBytes, incomingBytes.Length - blockRemaining, temp, 0, blockRemaining);

                byte[] decryptedChunk = cipher.DoFinal(temp);
                Array.Copy(decryptedChunk, 0, outcomingBytes, incomingBytes.Length - blockRemaining, blockRemaining);
                //Increase(IV); Why do I need to increse iv by hand?
            }

            return outcomingBytes;
   }

   private void Increase(byte[] iv)
   {
            for (var i = 0; i < iv.Length; i++)
            {
                iv[i]++;
                if (iv[i] != 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

At first glance, this code should work fine. But it does not. Pay attention to commented-out-lines:
//cipher.Init(false, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(Key), IV));
and
//Increase(IV); Why do I need to increase iv by hand?
Only if I uncomment them my code works fine.

I'm wondering why I have to increase the counter manually? Or I made a mistake somewhere in set-up in the constructor? I'm not very familiar with Bouncy Castle.

P.S. I'm using BC 1.8.6.1 version from Nuget.

Comment: The question is why you are buffering in the first place (or indeed, why you need this code at all). You are using a buffered cipher, right? Just perform multiple `ProcessBytes` and always a `DoFinal` and you'd be alright. Don't forget to concat the results together. I'll vote you up none-the-less as it doesn't explain the **why**.

Comment: Note that you are not resetting the cipher anywhere. You should always re-init the cipher *per encryption*. This won't happen if you keep it as a field. Generally, only the *key* should be a field. And note that it generally doesn't take much time to create / init a cipher anyway. I use cipher instances just once.

Comment: So, you are saying, that re-init each time is expected and right-way of doing it?

Comment: Yes, if just because you want to update the IV at each run. Normally the IV - the start of the counter for CTR mode - is prefixed to the counter value. In the case of CTR mode I'd use an explicit nonce and then fill the other rightmost bytes with zero (the counter is a big endian value as you've implemented). Of course there is no need to include the zero bytes, you only have to store the nonce. You can also use a counter on both sides, but updating the nonce is of absolute importance for CTR. Without it you basically loose all confidentiality.